# clear myAndridApp data from emulator Command

Tags: android

is there is a command to clear myAndridApp data from emulator

i'm developing a app and I don't want to go to mange-app ->myapp -> clear data
each time

App api 10 ,
emulator API :17

I dont want to uninstall the app or stop it
all i need to clear its stored data

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer to my question

```
adb shell pm clear [packgeName]
```

this command will clean all the data from the app

Answer (score 0):

You can close one by his pid using

```
adb shell kill <PID>
```

but I'm not sure of doing it with a package name.

However to kill the process you should use **am**:

```
am force-stop: force stop everything associated with <PACKAGE>.

am kill: Kill all processes associated with <PACKAGE>.  Only kills.
  processes that are safe to kill -- that is, will not impact the user
  experience.
```

for example:

```
adb shell am force-stop <YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME>
```

**or**

```
am force-stop YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME
```

**or**

```
adb killall YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to clear the app data, then use adb shell to enter into the app data folder and do a rm command each time you want the data cleared:

for example, do this once:

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/<package name>
rm -r *
```

then from the same command line window, fire this command each time you want the data cleared:

```
rm -r *
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want to uninstall the app I just want to clear its data like regstration info in my case